# Laravel route view name declaration not showing up

Tags: laravel, routes

I have created routes in `routes/web.php`.

```php
Route::prefix('home')->group(function () {
    Route::view('/', 'landing.index', ['name' => 'landing.home']);
    Route::post('/', 'SignupController@signup');
    Route::view('thank-you', 'landing.thank-you', ['name' => 'landing.thankyou']);
});
```

However, when calling `php artisan route:list` it shows me:

```
| Domain | Method   | URI            | Name  | Action                                             | Middleware  |
+--------+----------+----------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+-------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | home           |       | Illuminate\Routing\ViewController                  | web         |
|        | POST     | home           |       | App\Http\Controllers\SignupController@signup       | web         |
|        | GET|HEAD | home/thank-you |       | Illuminate\Routing\ViewController                  | web         |
```

Also, the name is not being registered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
Route::prefix('home')->group(function () {
 Route::view('/', 'landing.index')->name('landing.home');
    Route::post('/', 'SignupController@signup');
    Route::view('thank-you', 'landing.thank-you')->name('landing.thankyou');
});
```

Hope it helps.